# GUI display exhibits disparities between the local machine and the Flutter sandbox in Codelab

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i was practising flutter layout at
https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#putting-it-all-together.

Things were going well in the sandbox but the moment i tried to replacate the same thing on my local machine , the output generated  was not expected. 
Codelab code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 50),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Samrat Patel',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                ),
                const Text('App Developer'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Text('Noida,india'),
            Text('99XXXXXXXX'),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: const [Icon(Icons.accessibility)
                           ,Icon(Icons.timer),
                           Icon(Icons.phone_android),
                           Icon(Icons.phone_iphone),],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[Codelab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osuue.png)

local machine:

my main.dart file contains:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyWidget()));
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Expanded(
       child: Column(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
     children: [
       Row(
         children: [
           const Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
             child: Icon(
               Icons.account_circle,
               size: 50,
               textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
             ),
           ),
           Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             children: [
               Text(
                 'Samrat Patel',
                 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                 textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
               ),
               const Text(
                 'App Developer',
                 textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ],
       ),
       const SizedBox(height: 8),
       Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
         children: const [
           Text(
             'Noida,india',
             textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
           ),
           Text(
             '99XXXXXXXX',
             textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
           ),
         ],
       ),
       const SizedBox(height: 16),
       Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
         children: const [
           Icon(Icons.accessibility),
           Icon(Icons.timer),
           Icon(Icons.phone_android),
           Icon(Icons.phone_iphone),
         ],
       ),
     ],
   ));
 }
}
```

Output:[Output in myAndroid phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rmgj.png) 
So i am using my android device to view my app instead of an emulator.

Why fonts become red and large ?
why no icons were rendered?
why its not in the middle ?
why everything broked?